# Javascript not identifying click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Currently I have a page where there are 3 panels I can drag and drop.  On these panels I have 3 glyphs one for zooming, one for deleting and one for edit.  Take for example the deletion glyph, when I click this it should remove the whole  section within the page.  This works if I do not drag and drop the panel that I want to delete.  However once I drag it over to a new position, my javascript does not seem to recognize the glyph/click event anymore.

Here is my javascript code for deleting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-trash").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".col-md-4").remove();
    });
});
```

and here is the HTML for the panels I am attempting to delete after I drag and drop.

```
<div class="row" id="columns">
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="testchart">
            <!--CHART GOES HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-backcolour">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in panel-icons"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also here is my js code for drag and dropping

```
    //For reference tutorial can be found here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
    // Target (this) element is the source node.
    this.style.opacity = "1.0";

    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", this.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    e.target.classList.add("over");
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove("over");  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
        // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    }

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.

    [].forEach.call(columns, function (column) {
        column.classList.remove("over");
    });
}

var columns = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

[].forEach.call(columns, function (column) {
    column.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart, false);
    column.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false)
    column.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
    column.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave, false);
    column.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
    column.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

Comment: Would be nice if you show the same in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#columns').on('click', '.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".col-md-4").remove();
    });
});
```

From jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

On a side note, see [suggestion from ImreNage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30215699/3549014) about removing `.col-md-4` instead of `.panel`.

Comment: Hi Gyrocode that worked perfectly,  can you explain a little on how it differs from my code?

Comment: Also would this work, if I was to let the user add panels during runtime?

Comment: @Johnathon64, click events would be delegated as long as your new panels stay inside element with id `columns`. Otherwise define a new container that would hold all your panels and use its selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it, you seem to drag this element:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
```

out of it's parent:

```
<div class="col-md-4 column">
```

and then look for the parent to delete it:

```
$(this).closest(".col-md-4").remove();
```

Which is not there anymore. Try to move the whole container as one instead or delete one level below:

```
$(this).closest(".panel").remove();
```

Comment: This has just made me realise a flaw in my logic, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hi @ImreNagy,  I have done as you said, which worked however, if I delete the middle panel and try to move another panel in that empty space it does not let me.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Cos that I already have code in place I thought maybe it would only be a small tweak.  I've only just started html and javascript.